# Modifying primitive data types Arduino

Tags: c, arduino, primitive

Can you change the behavior of primitive data types in the Arduino source code. I presume these are all interpreted by the compiler.Can char be changed to always behave as unsigned instead of signed?

Comment: gcc has the compiler options -fsigned-char and -funsigned-char which switches chars to be signed or unsigned on a global scale. If you aren ot using gcc probably your compiler has similar options.

Comment: I am using gcc. So how would I implement that?

Comment: In C 'char' can be both signed or unsigned. Whether it is signed or unsigned depends on the compiler and/or compiler settings. In your case just provide -funsigned-char when invoking the compiler. Doing so 'signed char' will be signed, 'unsigned char' and 'char' will both be unsigned.

Comment: Thank it worked a treat :)

Comment: My advice is to not do this. Most people reading C could would expect `int` and `char` to be signed. To switch that behaviour with a compiler directive is very obscure. Compiler directives are not visible when you read code. Just choose the unsigned type explicitly (in code).

Answer (score 1):

In C 'char' can be both signed or unsigned. Whether it is signed or unsigned depends on the compiler and/or compiler settings. In your case just provide -funsigned-char when invoking the compiler. Doing so 'signed char' will be signed, 'unsigned char' and 'char' will both be unsigned

Answer (score 0):

In Arduino you'll need the IDE version 1.5 and higher.

This will allow you to access platform.txt where you can set the command line parameters pointed out by Meixner.

In 1.5.7 I found it here: `{ArduinoInstall}\arduino-1.5.7\hardware\arduino\avr\platform.txt`

There are two entries: `compiler.c.flags` & `compiler.cpp.flags` where you can add the switch `-funsigned-char`

Answer (score 0):

In Arduino all primitives can be both signed and unsigned just by adding unsigned in front of the definiton
`unsigned int example;
unsigned char example;`